# How do we scan barcode in Salesforce?

Tags: sales-cloud

I wanted to know is it possible to scan barcode with the scanner device and populate the information in Salesforce. If yes, how do we do it?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, handheld scanning devices act just like any other input device.  Simply put your cursor in the field where you want the bar code's numbers and scan the barcode. The numbers will show up in that field.

Comment: Having personally implemented this, that's approximately correct. Set the scanner to Keyboard Mode, possibly set up a separator key (e.g. tab or enter), capture the key in JavaScript do to lookups or whatever, and that's it.

Comment: I've done this. The curve ball for me was that the scanners were setup to append the [Enter} key (chr 13) which resulted in a premature form submission. I had to inhibit that default browser behavior because I wasn't allowed to change the scanner setup.

Comment: So I guess the caveat is that your experience may vary based on your scanner and what settings you can modify for it.  My particular one was simply plug and play with no settings available.  It probably did an auto CR, but I was just scanning into Excel so that was fine for my implementation.  If it's a VF page, you could deny the form submission on enter using Javascript.  There's lots of answers on the internet that tells you how to do that.